# Eager evaluation for Java: How does this example work?

Tags: java, lazy-evaluation

If I have a Java method :

```
public void foo (int a)
{
    //do something
}
```

Then I call this method:

```
foo (2/0)  or foo (2/4)
```

When does `2/0` or `2/4` get evaluated? Is it evaluated before it goes into the input of the function? Or does it get evaluated before it calls the function? (so is it evaluated inside or outside the function?)

---

In addition, consider:

```
if  (true) then { A } else { B }
```

I know A will be evaluated. However B will not evaluated even though java is an eager language?

Thank you!

Comment: This code is *not* Java. If you post Java code -please make sure it compiles first!

Comment: java uses call by value mechanism i.e when u call a function which uses  lazy evaluation strategy then arguments are first evaluated and then passed to function.

Answer (score 1):

`foo (2/0)`  or `foo (2/4)` might be evaluated by the compiler and replaced by the constant result (though the former should cause an `ArithmeticException` in runtime, so I'm not sure how the compiler can handle it. In general, `foo(a/b)` will be evaluated before the result of `a/b` is passed to `foo`.

In your `if` statement, you are correct that B won't be evaluated if the condition is true.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Well, I tried the code in my Eclipse IDE and it compiles and throws an exception in runtime. I guess the compiler doesn't optimize it.

Comment: Yeah. Fair enough. Tried here too. :)

Comment: In runtime, 2/4 is evaluated inside or outside the function? public void foo (int a){a+1}. When it goes inside the method and do a+1, a is 0.5 already or still unevaluated 2/4 ?

Comment: @Sonya It is evaluated outside the method. The method would actually get 0, not 0.5, since it's a division of ints and the result is int.

Answer (score 0):

**Question1:**

The type have been checked at compile time and the expression evaluates at run time. And the expression evaluates first and then the method calls.

For example :

```
foo (2/0)
```

That compiles fine and youl'l get exception while evaluating the expression at runtime.

**Question2:**

```
if (true)then{ A } else { B }
```

B won't evaluate. That is how the conditional expressions works. Evaluating both expression makes no sense.